# Display SharePoint lookup field on publishing website

Tags: sharepoint, moss, lookup-field

A page within our MOSS publishing website has a property which is a lookup field.

I only want the selected text to be displayed when you view the page not in edit mode, but when I use the `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.LookupField` it generates a hyperlink to the SharePoint list item (obviously bad).

Is there a way around this, short of creating my own lookup field control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a jQuery hack

[Using JQuery to remove Linked List Items hyperlinks.](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/?p=106)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('a[href*="RootFolder=*"]').each(
      function(index) {
         var link = $(this);
         $(this).after("<span>" + link.text() + "</span>");
         $(this).remove();
      });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem also.  The only way I found was to create my own control.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the link;

You can create a displaytemplate.ascx as below

> SharePoint:RenderingTemplate ID="LookupDisplayTemplate" runat="server">
>       &blockquote&Template>
>           &blockquote&SharePoint:FieldValue ID="FieldValue1" runat="server" ControlMode="Display"/>
>       &blockquote&/Template>
>     &blockquote&/SharePoint:RenderingTemplate>

Then. use it as below.

&blockquote&SharePoint:LookupField id="LookupField1" FieldName="" runat="server" DisplayTemplateName="LookupDisplayTemplate"/>

Then it works.

Hope it helps :)

Sebnem